# Best way to represent performing an operation on an association in a RESTful way?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Say I have a "user" resource and a "group" resource. RESTful representations of them would look like;

```
/user/:id
/group/:id
```

But what if I want to perform an operation on the association between the two resources? For example, if I wanted to specify that user #1 wanted to join group #1. How would I represent that group#join of group #1 should be executed on user #1?

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if I wanted to specify that user #1 wanted to join group #1. How would I represent that group#join of group #1 should be executed on user #1?

I would probably do a POST to something like /groups/1/members or /users/1/memberships. If you want to allow a user to join multiple groups at once, it might make sense to provide an alternative like a PUT to /users/1/memberships.

You have a number of options, but it comes down to the workflow you want to achieve. I think it helps to forget about REST for a little while. Think about building a simple browser app. Where are the links and forms? Each page in your web app is an HTML representation of a resource. It has links and forms. Replace that with alternative representations, but keep the links and forms.

Once you've gone through a design exercise like that, you'll be in a better position to decide whether a POST to /groups/1/members makes sense.

John

Comment: This isn't for a browser app, it's for an API. Flexibility is very important. I'm looking for opinions on best practice.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest that you develop a browser app, just suggested that it might help to think about it that way as you're designing your REST API. I'm not sure you're going to find best practices for URL design, beyond the basics of when to POST and when to PUT. Again, it comes down to how you want the workflow to come together. If you're allowing the client to set all memberships at once, a PUT to /users/1/memberships may make sense. If not, a POST to users/1/memberships or groups/1/members. There is no one best practice here.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. Is it the details of what you would be sending to the server that you're looking for?

Maybe something like this:
POST /groups/1/users

<User><Name>john.howes</Name><Id>1</Id></User>

Or whatever makes sense for the media type you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. What does /group/:id contain?

Im presuming it will contain a collection of users somewhere?

/group/:id/users/:id - would represent my membership to the group.

Mike Brown

Comment: /group/:id is just a JSON representation of the group document in the database.